# Iterar tabla en php en array de Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html5, ajax

Hola tengo la siguiente tabla que estoy llamado usando un controlador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Controlador**

```
$respuesta = GestorOITModels::obtenerViasModel("transporte"); //nombre de la tabla
$datos = array($respuesta);
echo json_encode($datos);
```

**Archivo JS, donde trato de guardar la tabla**

```
$(".content-wrapper").ready(function(){

    var vias;

    $.ajax({
        url: "views/ajax/OIT.php",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(respuesta) {
            if (respuesta == 0) {
                console.log("malo");

            } else {
                vias=respuesta[0];
                console.log("Primer console", vias);
                vias.forEach( function(valor, indice, array) {
                    console.log("En el índice " + indice + " hay este valor: " + valor);});
            }
        }
    });
})
```

Pero cuando uso el console del navegador queda asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Datos arrojado usando JSON.stringify(respuesta)**

```
[[{"0":"AEREO","tipo":"AEREO"},{"0":"DIRECTO","tipo":"DIRECTO"},{"0":"MARITIMO","tipo":"MARITIMO"},{"0":"OTROS","tipo":"OTROS"},{"0":"TERRESTRE","tipo":"TERRESTRE"}]]
```

Que debo corregir para que cuando lo itere nuevamente me quede por ejemplo:
`"Via[0]="AEREO"-Via[1]="DIRECTO"`, etc.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Necesitamos el contenido de JSON para conocer el nombre de los elementos que debes mostrar. PD: Ya he visto la captura de pantalla.. voy a redactar respuesta.

Comment: en vez demostrar una captura de pantalla, sería mucho mejor si imprimieras el contenido del objeto como texto, por ejemplo, copiando lo que te devuelve `JSON.stringify(vias)`

Comment: ¿Te sirvió mi respuesta? Veo que editaste tu pregunta. Si necesitas alguna aclaración o hacerme alguna consulta de mi respuesta envía un comentario.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio tu respuesta.

Comment: De nada @Baker1562 , no olvides marcarla como correcta pulsando sobre el icono **✔** que hay en la parte superior izquierda de mi respuesta. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que estás teniendo es que cada elemento de la matriz es un objeto que tiene dos propiedades con el mismo valor, por lo que si tratas de mostrar su contenido te dirá que es de tipo `Object`.

Para mostrar su contenido debes indicar la propiedad que deseas mostrar, te agrego varios ejemplos de cómo acceder a cada uno de ellos:

```js
vias = [
  {0: 'AEREO', tipo: 'AEREO'},
  {0: 'DIRECTO', tipo: 'DIRECTO'},
  {0: 'MARITIMO', tipo: 'MARITIMO'},
];
console.log("Primer console", vias);
vias.forEach( function(valor, indice, array) {
  console.log(
    "En el índice " + indice +
    " hay este valor (propiedad 'tipo'): " + valor.tipo +
    " (desde ['tipo']): " + valor['tipo'] +
    " (desde [0]): " + valor[0]
  );
});
```